# Why this VBA code has a compile error: Expected End Sub?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

```
Sub work()
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = Target * 1000
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I found a way to solve this problem by not using excel. I used R to solve this problem. Just a one tip, do not use excel if you have many data. It is deadly slow and complicated. Anyone can use R or Python in simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

you got to sub with 1 end sub.  sub work() and private sub....

```
Sub work() 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 

Application.EnableEvents = False Target = Target * 1000 Application.EnableEvents = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: what? I don't get it. Are you saying that I need two "End Sub" for "Sub work()" and "Private Sub"? I tried that but It doesnt work.

Comment: yes, you cannot have nested sub routines.  If you take out sub work(), it should work or take out Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: comment out your code and just put this in, Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox "hello alex"

End Sub


start typing in cells and you will see that the code works.  If you want to create your own routine, insert a module and do it there, and if you want to reference your module in the change event, you can call it from there....

Comment: The reason I put Sub work() is that VBA keep asking me to create the sub macro name for whatever. And I tried lot of ways to activate the code but not working. if I take out  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range), the code not working as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe VBA allows for nested subroutines or functions (though I think VB "proper" can do this).

Your problem is that you are starting a second subroutine while the first one is still "active", which is why it's complaining.

Easiest solution, assuming both subroutines are needed, is probably just to separate your subroutines rather than trying to nest them.

However, since it's not clear from your code snippet why you need `work()` at all, it *may* be that you can simply remove that line and just have the `Worksheet_Change()` subroutine, something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = Target * 1000
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you *do* need a separate function which basically does the same thing, write it (separately) so that it calls that one, or put the meat of the code into a *separate* subroutine which is called by both `work()` *and* `Worksheet_Change()`.

Comment: When I tried that code, Visual Basic wants me to create a macro name. And it creates Compile error as Fxxxxx endless loop.

Comment: @Alex, that's a totally separate issue from the nested subroutine issue. Accepted practice here is to try and keep questions relatively targeted. In other words, if the initial problem is solved, raise a *new* question for other problems. Otherwise, SO becomes a discussion board, rather than a Q&A resource - that was never its intention.